# What is Encoding -> Unicode in Internet Explorer and Firefox?

Tags: firefox, internet-explorer, encoding, unicode

As far as I know Unicode itself is not an encoding system. It is just a standard that assigns code point to characters. Quoting from Wikipedia..

> Unicode can be implemented by different character encodings.

So what are these options in Internet Explorer and Firefox?

[image]

[image]

Does Unicode implicitly mean UTF16? If so, is it BE or LE?

and while we are at it, is UTF-32 not supported by Firefox & Internet Explorer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Unicode` means *"Windows's"* encoding system (no, this is *not* invented by Microsoft, but widely used in its products), i.e. `UCS-2` (Universal Character Set).

In the past it was not so bad decision (slow processors have less problems with fixed length of characters), but today is `UTF-8` prevalent for very good reasons.

No, `UTF-32` is **not** supported - neither in Internet browsers, nor in another applications because its obvious disadvantage - 4 bytes for every character.

(Of course, they may be some exceptions.)

Comment: Chrome seems to support it.

Comment: @KorayTugay - Google wants to support *everything* regardless of its practical usefulness. Pure competition's reasons sometimes.

Comment: I see, thanks for the great answer. Is UCS-16 same with UTF-16?

Comment: Oh, I made a mistake (and I corrected it in my answer) - not UCS-16 (as 16 bits) but `UCS-2` (as 2 bytes). No, `UCS-2` is a **character set**  (every character as `2 bytes`) while `UTF-16` is an *extension* of `UCS-2` and it is a *variable-length* **coding scheme** (`2 to 4 bytes` for a character). On the other hand, for majority of the 65,536 characters (the `UCS-2` range) they have identical code points, so *they are largely equivalent*.